# York Diamond 80 HVAC - Fan Only Works With Heat

Tags: hvac

Model P4HUB16N08001A.  NEST thermostat says problem with wiring - relay clicks but fan does not start - outside unit runs.  Installed "dumb" thermostat and fuse blows - does not try to start.  Fan does work on HEAT, but not for COOL or FAN.  Originally one of the guys thought it was the run capacitor, which did test weak so replaced - not the problem.

Comment: Does jumpering R to G at the air-handler cause the fan to come on?

Comment: Jumpering across R to G blows the fuse.

Comment: Can you remove the existing wire from the G terminal, put a fresh fuse in, and try that test again? Want to see if there's a wiring issue, or if the control board's where the short is.

Comment: Fan does run with jumper from R to G and green wire disconnected.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the problem - we were too close to see it.  Replacing the thermostat cable has resolved the issue - it was pinched between ducts in the attic and had worn through the insulation and developed a short circuit on the green wire.

Comment: Mind posting that as an answer please? i'll give you a +1 for it

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for pointing me to the problem - we were too close to see it. Replacing the thermostat cable has resolved the issue - it was pinched between ducts in the attic and had worn through the insulation and developed a short circuit on the green wire.

Comment: Like that, ThreePhaseEel?

Comment: There you go :)